# Applovin Ad Integration

Tags: java, android, applovin

Please, I'm new to Applovin.
How to connect Applovin Banner and Reward Ad in one activity in android, I check the GitHub code and each ad unit is on seperate activity.

When I first added the banner ad, it worked well, but when I added the reward ad that's when I the layout refused to load.

So please help me out with a code to fix this issue

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Please make sure to set the mediation provider value to "max" to ensure proper
        // functionality
        AppLovinSdk.getInstance(this).setMediationProvider("max");
        AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(
                this,
                new AppLovinSdk.SdkInitializationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSdkInitialized(final AppLovinSdkConfiguration configuration) {
                        // AppLovin SDK is initialized, start loading ads
                        createBannerAd();
                    }
                });

        
        createInterstitialAd();
        createRewardedAd();        
}
 
/** BANNER AD **/
    void createBannerAd() {
        adView = new MaxAdView("ad unit id", this);

        ....
    }
    

    /*************************************************************************/
    
    /** INTERSTITIAL AD * */
    void createInterstitialAd() {
        interstitialAd = new MaxInterstitialAd("ad unit id", this);
        interstitialAd.setListener(this);

        // Load the first ad
        interstitialAd.loadAd();
    }
    
    /*************************************************************************************/

/** REWARDED AD * */
    void createRewardedAd() {
        rewardedAd = MaxRewardedAd.getInstance("ad unit id", this);
        rewardedAd.setListener(this);

        rewardedAd.loadAd();
    }

    // MAX Ad Listener
    @Override
    ...
    
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling to initialize an interstitial ad an a rewarded ad outside of the listener that listens for the applovin initialization status.

Comment: Thanks have figured it out